# I do not wish Gmail contacts to appear on my device

Tags: contacts

I'm using the same Gmail account for Google Play with two cell phones. I do not wish for one of those phones to sync the contacts in my account, but it has done so automatically. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the device's Settings, under Accounts tap Google, tap the @gmail.com address, uncheck Sync Contacts and Sync People Details.

To remove already synced contacts go the phone Settings menu, Application Manager, go to All applications, then Clear Data for the Contacts and Contacts Storage apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on your settings depending on what phone you're using there should be an "account" section where you can click on your gmail account which will bring up the sync settings, in these settings there should be a contact tick box, untick this box and the contacts should be removed.

As mentioned, this is depending on the make of the phone as steps could vary
In future, it is best to give as much information as is possible